# What are the differences between a bible encyclopedia and a bible dictionary? Why would someone use one versus the other?

Tags: tools-of-biblical-studies

What are the differences between a bible encyclopedia and a bible dictionary? Why would someone use one versus the other? This is in relation to doing hermeneutics.

Comment: I think they're basically the same. An actual dictionary of the Biblical languages is however called a lexicon instead. Rather confusing.

Comment: thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

This may help you: Think of a regular dictionary such as Websters or any that you are familiar with. You use it to look up words that you don't understand. The same is true of a Bible dictionary. Use it to look up words that you aren't familiar with. Regarding a "regular" encyclopedia, you use it to read more details about a certain subject. The same is true about a Bible encyclopedia. You use it to read more about a specific subject that is in the Bible. An encyclopedia has much more detail and has a different purpose than a dictionary does. Hope this helps you know which one to use at various times as you study the Word of God. God bless YOU.

Comment: thanks for answering